# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined - C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to set the source of a resource dictionary in c# to a location of a folder within the project, but get the above error.

Could someone advise what the issue is please?

Heres the code:

```
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("../Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml");
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Since this is a file path, use \ instead of /.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use  [UriKind.Relative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx)

```
myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("../Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml",  UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 4):

I kept running into the same issue even after passing the `UriKind.Relative` argument. The weird bit was that some of the Uris to XAML pages were working using the method @Magnus suggested - but most of them would throw the:

`The format of the URI could not be determined`

exception.

Finally, I read up on **[Pack Uris](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/04/pack-uri-to-reference-component.html)** for WPF applications which solved my problem a 100%.

I started using urls like this:

```
// ResourceFile is in the Root of the Application
myResourceDictionary.Source = 
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

or

```
// ResourceFile is in the Subfolder of the Application
myResourceDictionary.Source = 
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SubFolder/ResourceFile.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Hope this helps someone struggling with the same issues I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set the background of a window to an ImageBrush.

Changing UriKind.Absolute to UriKind.Relative fixed the problem for me.

```
private void SetBackgroundImage()
{
    ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource =
        new BitmapImage(new Uri("background.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
    };
    this.Background = myBrush;
}
```