# How to change absolute URI to relative?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I wish I could change the path of the source image, to match the folder of my project.

Current code

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Referenciel/WpfApplication1/Resources/bateleur.gif"));
```

What I am trying to set up

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Referenciel\WpfApplication1\Resources\bateleur.gif"));
```

But I have an error : Invalid URI - Unable to determine the URI format.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342123/how-to-get-relative-path-of-a-file-in-visual-studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\Resources\bateleur.gif", UriKind.Relative));
```

**EDIT**:

In the image Properties window set **Build Action** to **Resource**.

Comment: The code works but it does not display the image

Comment: In the image Properties is your Build Action: Resource?

Comment: I change the setting "Build Action: Resource" and it works. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you

Comment: While this *may* work, the correct way to load an image resource is a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), like `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/bateleur.gif")`

Answer (score -1):

Don't start your path with a `\`.

### Edit

This one should solve your question.

Original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9738235).

```
img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Referenciel\WpfApplication1\Resources\bateleur.gif", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thank you but it did not solve the problem

Comment: @Manudog Edited answer. Anyway, you should consider using pack URI.